# How can I use python api in node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, integration

Is where a way to use python api in node js?
I want use this api - https://github.com/billy-yoyo/RainbowSixSiege-Python-API for my node js app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it as terminal commands using:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

exec(scriptToRun, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
     return;
   }
```